# How to design a mission to visit several locations and in each location process some computer vision tasks on the mobile platform?

Tags: dji-sdk

I would need to make my dron Mavic2 Pro to visit approx 10 locations in relatively low altitude 1.7 m. In each location the camera should look at right direction and the mission paused to let the mobile application process some CV tasks. I am not sure what is the best approach to make a mission that is partially processed on mobile platform? What to use in DJI mobile sdk api to pause mission when the location is reached?

I am going to use a time line mission composed from sequence of `GoToAction`. I wonder if this is a good way to do it. Is there a better solution?

Is [MissionControl.Listener](https://developer.dji.com/cn/mobile-sdk/documentation/faq/cn/api-reference/android-api/Components/Missions/DJIMissionControl.html#djimissioncontrol_addlistenertotimelineprogresswithblock_inline) right place to interrupt a mission when a TimeLineElement finish or should I use [WaypointReachedTrigger](https://developer.dji.com/cn/mobile-sdk/documentation/faq/cn/api-reference/android-api/Components/Missions/DJIMissionTrigger_DJIWaypointReachedMissionTrigger.html)?
I wasn't able to find any suitable example.

Answer (score 0):

Please add specific programming question. Otherwise, all answer is primarily opinion-based see https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask for detail

DJI method allows you to control the drones gimbal and gps navigation through MissionAction. The gotoaction is a subclass of the Missionaction class. the gotoaction only goes to some GPS location . So you need other things in the mission action such as gimbalattiudeaction and camera capture action to perform camera pointing and capturing. See the Fig below.

[image]

For CV tasks, it is easy to link DJI app to OpenCV. But I highly not recommend you to do so as the task such as dection using CNN system takes too much resources. The popular approach is to upload the image taken in local buffer to a local server with GPU for processing in near real-time manner. See the Fig below, I`m using WSDK with windows online OCR for detection. Video at https://youtu.be/CcndnHkriyA . I tried with local phone based approch, but result is limited by the model accuracy. And I could not apply high accuracy model because of the processing demand for such model is high. You can see my demo in the Fig below
[image]

What you want is pretty ez to implement but hard to perfect. Flying in low altitude(1.7m) requires you to have some degree of obstacle avoidance and GPSless path planning. The one implemented in Mavic hardware is only simple avoidance or slip through. For a bit more complex like go around a wall or maze-like environment, it better to add your own global path planer and local path planner. For the feedback you can use the SVO method to get odometry and map the local sparse obstacle map for inflated radius calculation. See Fig below.

Fig taken from video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YnIMfw6bJY.

The feedback code is available at https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo.

The path planning code you can try with ETH`s https://github.com/ethz-asl/mav_voxblox_planning as well.

Good luck with your work.
[image]

Comment: I use [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite) for CV task to find an object and center camera on it.

Comment: then should be easy to interface

Comment: I just need an advise about DJI Mibile SDK API. What to use to interrupt TimeLineMission?

Comment: at one GPS point you declare a node class which inside you set the GPS long lat alt camera heading, action, loiter radius, ending criteria etc etc..   then push it back to the mission list.  load the node one by one to the list. then upload the mission list and execute.